How do websites comply with every single international privacy law (e.g. GDPR)?
I've been at companies that went through the effort of complying with the GDPR regulation. It was massively difficult. But that is just one regulation of many, worldwide.
Since many websites are built by small teams on a small budget, but are available worldwide, how can they possibly comply with all of these laws?
I understand that many may not follow the law, but I also know that many will try to follow the law, but it seems incredibly complicated, beyond what's possible except for extremely large corporations.
The internet makes it very easy to launch a website which operates globally, e.g. any SaaS platform can easily operate globally.
Some examples:

I decide to make a personal website with a blog, and allow people to comment on it. When they comment, the create an account upload a photo, their name, birth date, and location. This website is available globally.
I make a "to do" app which helps you keep track of your groceries. This app costs $1/year and is available globally. Users create an account where they upload their personal info, and input tasks which may include what could be considered protected data.
I make a "meet other Harry Potter fans in your city" website. Users can use the website to discover other fans in their area, and can even choose to host an event. Users can chat with eachother and upload all sorts of personal data. This website is available globally.
I build an empty webpage that is available globally. I use  tracking pixels and cookies from Google and Meta and other various services to gather usage analytics.


Why would a website have to follow every international privacy law? Wouldn't they only have to follow the ones where they intend to interact with customers/users?

I'm talking about websites which interact with customers/users worldwide. This is super common, basically every SaaS product is open to anyone worldwide to purchase.

You might want to clarify in your question as when I read the question it seems like you are talking about small websites in general and not companies that do business around the globe and their website.

There are certainly some activities in which it simply isn't economically efficient to conduct business unless you are a big corporation and sometimes that's fine - not all activities are suitable for small businesses. Also, GDPR isn't a great example, because there aren't that many competing regimes out there (half a dozen maybe?). A better example might be sales tax, excise tax, and VAT collection for someone selling goods from a global website (which is insanely hard and facilitated by third-party intermediaries that make software figuring it out).

Also, while it is a fine line between asking for specific legal advice and providing enough detail to come up with a sensible answer, the law is incredibly fact rich and context specific. What makes sense of a cryptocurrency exchange and what makes sense for a dating website and what makes sense for an online hardware store website may not be very similar.

@ohwilleke I'm particularly interested in privacy laws. Taxes, though convoluted, are more clear cut. You sell something to someone in jurisdiction X, you figure out what taxes are owed in that jurisdiction. But privacy laws are far wider. Just visiting a site, users can leave a trail of personal data.

"It was massively difficult." then you need to work for better companies, maybe one's that do not exploit their users behind their backs. Seriously, some countries already had very similar laws before the GDPR came into effect EU wide (guess what the GDPR was modelled on). I have been working under those "new laws" for 30+ years now, they are not that complicated and certainly not "massively difficult".

Specifically for GDPR, it simply doesn't apply in many scenarios. As a rule of thumb, you only have to bother with GDPR if you actively participate in the EU Single Market (are based therein, or intend to have customers/users from Europe). In your scenarios, #1 and #4 don't show any intention to target people in the EU. #2 might count depending on whether you enable EU countries in the app store. #3 is more tricky due to location data and its interaction with Art 3(2)(b) GDPR, but the developer can avoid these problems by allowlisting the service only for specific regions.

@nvoigt You're speaking about difficultly levels, are you speaking from a technical background? If so, I would have loved to hire you to make some "easy" changes to our database and all the workflows and UIs that the depend on them in our 20 year old codebase, since it's so easy for you.

@brentonstrine Well, if you build your database and code flows to exploit your users privacy, then sure, change is ultra-hard. If you had your users best interest in mind 20 years ago, it should not be. Dont' get me wrong, I have seen whole business models fail due to better privacy laws... I would argue that that was the point of said laws.

@nvoigt It seems you have a dichotomy of either being GDPR compliant or exploitative, with no middle ground. Apps built without GDPR in mind may not have built ways to carefully track how data from a single user is used across various database tables. The assumption is that users give data to an app so that the app may use it to do what the customer asks. I wouldn't consider that exploitative at all. Not being able to easily track down every byte of data from a particular user to delete it may be bad programming, but how is it exploitative?

Imagine you were selling electrical extension cords rather than web services. An extension cord which is legal in the US may not be legal in the EU, and vice versa. (Even if it could pass safety certifications, it must actually be submitted for certification.) So even if you could have a webshop and sell internationally, you are not allowed to. No different for web services.
Ask the legal and compliance compartment to summarize the legal requirements and try to translate that into technical requirements which meet all or most of them.

Make a conscious decision to ignore some jurisdictions. For someone in the West, that might include North Korea, or Russia, but perhaps not China.
If jurisdiction A says you cannot use the customer email for spam, and jurisdiction B says you cannot sell it, then you cannot use it either for spam or sell it.
It is possible that requirements are contradictory. If jurisdiction A requires you to know your customer and document that, and jurisdiction B requires you to delete no-longer-necessary data, then either you look for language like "unless legally required" in jurisdiction B, or you are out of luck. Multiple instances of your website for multiple jurisdictions.



How do websites comply with every single international privacy law ... ?

They don't. It is impracticable.
Normally, they just aim to comply with those specific laws not complying with which in their view is likely to hit them back.
The subset of those laws is much much smaller than the set comprised of "every single international privacy law", and so is manageable.

FWIW, I suspect that the set comprised of "every single international privacy law" isn't nearly so large as it could be. I suspect that of the perhaps 300 or so jurisdictions (mostly national but some subnational) in the world that could enact internet privacy laws, that probably 10% of fewer have actually done so. If people care complying with EU and CA laws, why bother enacting your own.

Different markets have different requirements.  Europe has the GDPR, China has its firewall, Russia has sanctions, and the US have all their own laws.  Any website, from the smallest blog to the largest megacorp has to consider the pros and cons of complying with each set of rules.
As long as one is not actively doing business in any of these jurisdictions you are likely to be OK, but it is worth knowing what you are doing with respect to at least countries that are friendly with your own.
You say in a comment:

I'm particularly interested in privacy laws. Taxes, though convoluted, are more clear cut. You sell something to someone in jurisdiction X, you figure out what taxes are owed in that jurisdiction. But privacy laws are far wider. Just visiting a site, users can leave a trail of personal data. –

The GDPR is the strictest regulation.  I think that if you apply the rules of the GDPR to all your users you will comply with most privacy laws in all Western jurisdictions unless you are doing something particularly difficult such as healthcare.  If that is compatible with operation in China is a difficult question.
If you think the general principle is a problem you may be interested in the concept of Regulatory Capture.

This doesn't seem to address the issue of how they do it.

It does. “You comply with GDPR and pray”.

If you can’t stand the heat, get out of the kitchen
No one is forcing any given person to make a website, it’s a choice. Just like, say, driving a car is a choice.
If you choose to do either, you have to comply with all relevant laws (or accept the consequences of non-compliance). It may be, as you say “massively difficult” - if it’s not worth taking on the massively difficult task, don’t do it.
If you are going to do it, you need to invest the required resources in time, money, and education.

Question is not "can I break the law." The question is, how do people stand the heat?

@brentonstrine they invest the required resources
